# print occurrences of elements in an array list using java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I have created a logic to calculate occurrences of elements in an array list, But it's not printing in the exact order that i want. Below i have provided my code and my requirement.

I need in below format,

```
list: [1, 1, 5, 3, 7 ,7 ,7 , 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 1]
number: 1, count: 2
number: 5, count: 1
number: 3, count: 1
number: 7, count: 3
number: 3, count: 1
number: 11, count: 1
number: 2, count: 2
number: 3, count: 1
number: 1, count: 1
```

But, I am getting in below format,

```
list: [1, 1, 5, 3, 7 ,7 ,7 , 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 1]
number: 1, count: 3
number: 5, count: 1
number: 3, count: 3
number: 7, count: 3
number: 11, count: 1
number: 2, count: 2
```

Here's my code

```
package com.abc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyArrayListSort
{
public static void main(String []args){
new MyArrayListSort().start();
}
public void start() {
    List<Integer> list = getList(1, 1, 5, 3, 7 ,7 ,7 , 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 1);

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
        Integer retrievedValue = map.get(i);
        if (null == retrievedValue) {
            map.put(i, 1);
        }
        else {
            map.put(i, retrievedValue + 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("list: " + list);
    printCount(map);
}

private List<Integer> getList(int... numbers)
{
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i : numbers)
{
    list.add(i);
}
return list;
}

private void printCount(Map<Integer, Integer> map)
{
for (Integer key : map.keySet())
{
    System.out.println("number: " + key + ", count: " + map.get(key));
}
}
}
```

Comment: this is different question @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: If you look really, *really* close, you might be able to see past the illusion, and realize that there *are* three 1's in the list, two at the beginning and one at the end. Your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do, i.e. count the occurrences of each value. --- *Hint:* You cannot use `Map` for your "needed" result, because `Map`, by definition, cannot have duplicate keys, so it's impossible to use `Map` to have two result lines for value 1.

Comment: You're going to need something like a linked list here.  As @Andreas pointed out, a map won't work here.

Comment: yes i got it..can you please help me to formulate the logic or give some link of any article so that i will get some idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is probably the shortest version of code to solve this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 5, 3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 1);
System.out.println("list: " + list);
for (int i = 0, prev = -1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (i == list.size() - 1 || ! list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
        System.out.printf("number: %d, count: %d%n", list.get(i), i - prev);
        prev = i;
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
list: [1, 1, 5, 3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 1]
number: 1, count: 2
number: 5, count: 1
number: 3, count: 1
number: 7, count: 3
number: 3, count: 1
number: 11, count: 1
number: 2, count: 2
number: 3, count: 1
number: 1, count: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Logic:**
Keep track of currentValue and the number of times it repeats in continuous sequence. Once the number changes, insert the value and count so far, into the list.
Finally the left over value (final value in the list), push that value and count as well.

**Edit:**
You can remove the newList altogether and write print statement too as @Andreas pointed out in comment.

**Code:**

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 5, 3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 1);

List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>();

Integer previousValue = null;
Integer previousCount = 0;
for(Integer value : list) {
    if(previousValue == null) {
        previousValue = value;
        previousCount++;
    } else if(previousValue.intValue() == value.intValue()) {
        previousCount++;
    } else {
        newList.add(new Pair<>(previousValue, previousCount));
        previousValue = value;
        previousCount = 1;
    }
}
if(previousValue != null) {
    newList.add(new Pair<>(previousValue, previousCount));
}

for(Pair<Integer,Integer> pair : newList) {
    System.out.println(pair.getKey()  + ":" + pair.getValue());
}
```

**Output:**

```
1:2
5:1
3:1
7:3
3:1
11:1
2:2
3:1
1:1
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but your output does not show the final `1` from the input data.

Comment: Downvoters, please comment as to what is wrong so the answer can be corrected. The output expected from the question and the code is same.

Comment: I'm the down-voter because: 1) You're missing the last result of `number: 1, count: 1`. 2) Why build a list? Just print result directly. No need for `Pair` then. 3) `previousValue == value` is not the correct way to compare two `Integer` objects.

Comment: @Andreas Corrected the code for 1 and 1. I thought of it but forgot to write that. Added the intValue conversion as well. Also, the new list was created so he can use it. True, we can print it directly as well. But I guess that's upto the questioner to use how he likes it.